# std::thread Error C2893 in VS2015

Tags: c++, templates

```
// C2893.cpp
// OK in VS2013, Error in VS2015
// compile with: /EHsc
#include <thread>
//
template <typename T_app>
struct instance
{
    void load() {;}
};
//
template <typename T_app>
struct scene
{
    T_app *p_app;
    void thread_load() {
        std::thread(&instance<T_app>::load, std::ref(p_app->app_inst) ).detach();
    }
};
//
struct app
{
    instance<app> app_inst;
    scene<app> app_scene;
};
//
int main() {
    app my_app;
    my_app.app_scene.p_app = &my_app;
    // OK in VS2013, Error in VS2015
    my_app.app_scene.thread_load();
    return 0;
}
```

Hello, I just updated to VS2015, the code in VS2013 is OK, how to correct the mistake of `thread_load()`? I read Breaking Changes in Visual C++ 2015, It must be Non-type template parameters problem, but I can not find a right way. Thanks.

Comment: what evil magic is that semicolon for? `void load() {;}`

Comment: it is equivalent to `void load() {}` The semicolon is a blank statement (and should be discarded by the compiler).

Comment: You can try to work around it:  `std::thread([&]{ p_app->app_inst.load(); }).detach()`

Answer (score 1):

The error is here `std::ref(p_app->app_inst)`.
The second parameter of `std::thread` should be a `instance*` in this context but `p_app->app_inst` is just a `instance` class.

So the answer is `std::thread(&instance<T_app>::load, &p_app->app_inst ).detach();` without any lambda function.